# Trying to create a c++ PUT request with cURL with an object

Tags: c++, http, curl

Recently I want to PUT an object with c++ curl.
Terminal command like this:

```
PUT /ObjectName HTTP/1.1
Content-Length：ContentLength
Content-Type: ContentType
Host: BucketName.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com
Date: GMT Date
Authorization: SignatureValue
```

My code：

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://tva******.oss*****.aliyuncs.com");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, hd_src);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t)file_info.st_size);
auto size = to_string(file_info.st_size);
curl_slist* headerList = NULL;
headerList = curl_slist_append(headerList, ("Authorization: " + Authorization).c_str());
headerList = curl_slist_append(headerList, ("Date: " + finalTime).c_str());
headerList = curl_slist_append(headerList, ("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"));
headerList = curl_slist_append(headerList, ("Content-Length: " + size).c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerList);
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

But its effect is `PUT HTTP/1.1` not `PUT /ObjectName HTTP/1.1`
I want to put an object ,but there is no object, so it puts a bucket.
How to make a request like `PUT /ObjectName HTTP/1.1`.

Comment: Well, where do you expect the `/ObjectName` to be specified, in the shown code snippet? It's not going to appear out of thin air, by itself. Do you happen to know what `/ObjectName` represents, in HTTP? It's part of the URL, that goes without saying; so, are you asking for permission to shove `/ObjectName` into the `CURLOPT_URL` parameter? Well, I'm happy to announce that you have full and complete permission to do so!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik   Thanks! Should i change it like this ?  `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://tva******.oss*****.aliyuncs.com/test.zip");`

Comment: Well, I happen to still be wasting time on Stackoverflow. But let's say I wasn't, and I was planning to check back in tomorrow. What makes more sense to you: wait until tomorrow, or maybe someone else to reply, at some point, or take ten seconds to see if it works, by yourself? Which one do you think would result in a faster answer?

Comment: Sorry, I'm on my way to work, I'll try it later

Comment: It works . And after set `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);` I can read request headers and response headers. Thanks very much.

Comment: `("Content-Length: " + size).c_str()` is unnecessary.